# A system of three nonlinear equations

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multilinear-algebra

I have a system of nonlinear equations. Here it is:
$$
\frac{s_2 - K_2}{ps_2^{\gamma_1} + (1 - p)s_2^{\gamma_2}}  = \frac{K_1 - s_1}{ps_1^{\gamma_1} + (1 - p)s_1^{\gamma_2}} \\
\frac{s_2}{s_2 - K_2} = \frac{p\gamma_1s_2^{\gamma_1} + (1 - p)\gamma_2 s_2^{\gamma_2}}{ps_2^{\gamma_1} + (1 - p)s_2^{\gamma_2}} \\
\frac{s_1}{s_1 - K_1} = \frac{p\gamma_1s_1^{\gamma_1} + (1 - p)\gamma_2 s_1^{\gamma_2}}{ps_1^{\gamma_1} + (1 - p)s_1^{\gamma_2}}   
$$

Here Im need solutions for $s_1,s_2,p$. Im trying solve it at Wolfram, but it cut equaions off (too many characters).

Thx a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further consideration, I think there is no good non-numerical solution here.